# Is it secure using LWE-based cryptosystem under RLWE-based parameters?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto, lwe, ring-lwe

I'm computer guy having trouble with cryptography.

I recently read the BGV Homomorphic encryption paper which was constructed under both LWE and RLWE assumptions.

I was implementing Threshold version of BGV encryption [[AJW12]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-29011-4_29) using HElib optimized under the RLWE assumption, and I found out that [AJW12] proved the security under the LWE assumption.

A paper [[LN16]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-48965-0_8) says that the RLWE is a special instance of the LWE problem.

So, I think that [AJW12] encryption under RLWE parameters is still secure, but I'm not sure.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I right?

Possibly, but it's not guaranteed, even if we assume that LWE is secure.

RLWE is a special instance of LWE; however that doesn't mean that RLWE is secure if LWE is.  The LWE assumption holds if we have a random instance; that is, one chosen from a specific probability distribution.  The RLWE problem has a different probability distribution; one in which the vast majority of LWE instances have probability 0.  The probability that the LWE will choose an instance which has a nonzero probability for being a RLWE instance is negligible.  It may be that the RLWE instances happen to be weak; that would not practically impact the security of LWE.

Now, it's not known that any such weakness applies specifically to RLWE; however it's also not proven that there isn't, either.